# Writing data from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a 'recruitment spreadsheet' in which I want to record employee interviews and outcomes. For convenience I have created a separate sheet called 'Failed Candidates'. I want this to act as an easy point of reference to let candidates know of their failure.

[Tracking sheet - this is where all candidate info is stored, as well as outcomes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hciJe.png)

[This is the 'Failed Candidates' sheet - currently manually populated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifesf.png)

I would like Failed Candidates to auto generate.

WHEN OUTCOME ON 'TRACKER' SHEET = FAILED THEN COPY THE FOLLOWING FROM 'TRACKER' TO 'FAILED CANDIDATES'

First Name

Last Name

Email

Position

 R1 Date

 R1 Outcome

 R1 Feedback

 R2 Date

 R2 Outcome

 R2 Feedback

Comment: Try `worksheet_change` event.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use worksheet formulas to copy data from one sheet to another. What you describe is basically a report on the table with all the data.

There are several ways to create such a report, including:

- manually populate (as you are doing now)
- use Power Query to query the original data, filter by outcome, remove unwanted columns and load into the report sheet. Refresh when the original data table changes
- use a formula to generate a list of names that have the status "failed", for eg `=FILTER(<Name column in Table>,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("failed",<Outcome column in table>)))`, then use lookup formulas to pull data from the desired columns for each name
- use VBA and write code